# bundle exec throws an 'checked out' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I've runned `bundle exec foreman start` and I got this:

```
10:09:17 web.1  | /home/luiz/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/source.rb:574:in `rescue in load_spec_files': git://github.com/drnic/composite_primary_keys.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
```

All I've done was a `bundle update`...I know that I can run `--deployment` option on bundle install, but I don't want to store my gems inside my app bundle folder...
Any workarounds?

Comment: have you tried running bundle install as recommended in the line you've pasted?

Comment: yep...he just says 'bla bla bundle complete bla bla bla'

Comment: yes, I just updated the gem `foreman`